# How to set scrollable content dinamically in ng zorro table?

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular

I have a ng-zorro table and i would want the scroll bar to resize when i resize the browser window (say for example in a smaller device). So that it will be dinamically changed based on the page size, how to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, firstly you should provide more context to your question: for example you could provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)
and some code so we can have more context to the question asked.

But anyway i will try to answer your question:

**Here's what you can do:**

- looking at the [ng-zorro table](https://ng.ant.design/components/table/en) i see that there is a property for `nzScroll` that takes an object as argument.
- so when you delcare the table you can do this:

```html
<nz-table [nzScroll]="{ y: 'calc(100vh - 276px)' }">
</nz-table>
```

**What is that code doing?**

- So since we want to scroll vertically (and not horizontally) we need to change the y axis ence the `y:` in the code.
- you can assign a pixel value to that `y`but that will result your scrollbar to have a fixed height so resizing the window will not resize the scrollbar.
- what i did was calculate all the elements heights in my page so that i know how much height my table is taking. I did this when the table was empty using an extension for google chrome [smart page ruler extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/smart-page-ruler/nmibbjghlmdiafjolcphdggihcbcedmg)
- knowing the elements height in my page i could subtract that amount to the `viewHeight` of my page.
- Therefore everytime you resize the window the scrollbar is going to resize because is calculating the difference between 100% of the viewHeight and the sum between all of your elements heights.

If you have any question about my answer i will happly answer, cheers!

Comment: So how do i calculate that px in the minus operation?

Comment: @ludodev69 Use an extension to find the exact height of your elements. For example if you have a header, or a menu calculate how much they take in height based on the entire page. Once you have that you can simply subtract it to the `viewHeight`